# ViewPager set Page margin for all screens

Tags: java, android

I am making a carouel with android ViewPager. I need to show something like that
[image]

I need to show one element on the center of screen and a little part of another element on the sides (like in the image). I am trying with

```
viewPager.setPageMargin(-390);
```

But this doesn't work in all screens, how can I set the correct margin depending the density of the screen?

Comment: how did you achieved it?

Answer (score 2):

1.This is a background-to-foreground ViewPager,please try:

```
package com.eftimoff.viewpagertransformers;

import android.view.View;

public class BackgroundToForegroundTransformer extends BaseTransformer {

@Override
protected void onTransform(View view, float position) {
    final float height = view.getHeight();
    final float width = view.getWidth();
    final float scale = min(position < 0 ? 1f : Math.abs(1f - position), 0.5f);

    view.setScaleX(scale);
    view.setScaleY(scale);
    view.setPivotX(width * 0.5f);
    view.setPivotY(height * 0.5f);
    view.setTranslationX(position < 0 ? width * position : -width * position * 0.25f);
}

private static final float min(float val, float min) {
    return val < min ? min : val;
}

}
```

2.Please check this repository out. This effect is exactly what you want.

https://github.com/dolphinwang/ImageCoverFlow

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for a [dimension resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

In values/dimens.xml, add

```
<dimen name="page_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

Then in Java you can call

```
int marginPx = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.page_margin);
viewPager.setPageMargin(marginPx);
```